# My SQL insertion of values using java program

Tags: java, mysql

I have written this code to insert values in mysql ,I have already made database connection
I am getting this error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException`

```
public class JavaMysql {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bhuwan";
         String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
         String userName = "root";
         String password = "rpass"; 
         try {
             Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bhuwan","root","rpass");
             PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert in to xmltable values(?,?)");
             stmt.setInt(1,101);
             stmt.setString(2,"Nitish Sharma");
             stmt.execute();
             int i=stmt.executeUpdate();
             System.out.println(i+"records inserted");
             conn.close();
         }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
         }
}
```

Comment: `into` and not `in to`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is you have a space in `INTO` keyword,

```
insert in to xmltable values(?,?)  
         ^ causes the error
```

it should be

```
insert into xmltable values(?,?)
```

Comment: now i am getting a error:-com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '101' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: it just means there is already a value for the primary key the exists. do you have any auto increment column?